# How to recognize an update to OneToMany-relation done on the many side?

Tags: spring, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I've got a person-taxcase one to many relation:

in Person-class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
private List<TaxCaseEntity> taxCases = new ArrayList<>();
```

TaxCase-class:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersonEntity.class)
private PersonEntity person;
```

. Person can have multiple tax cases. When I create a new tax case like this:

```
 @Test
 @Transactional
public void test() {
    UUID personId = UUID.randomUUID();

    PersonEntity personEntity = createPersonEntity(mandantId);

    personRepository.save(personEntity);

    TaxCaseEntity taxCase = createTaxCase();
    taxCase.setPerson(personEntity);

    taxCaseRepository.save(taxCase);

    PersonEntity foundEntity = personRepository.findById(personId).get();
    assertThat(foundEntity.getId()).isEqualTo(personId);
}
```

Found entity has zero tax cases.
However, when I create it like this:

```
  PersonEntity personEntity = createPersonEntity(UUID.fromString("05e710ea-f8a4-40ba-b67c-8a685f35fc84"));
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(personEntity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    TaxCaseEntity taxCaseEntity = createTaxEntity()
                    .setPerson(personEntity);

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(taxCaseEntity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
```

The subsequent call to `personRepository.findById(..)` yields a person entity instance with one tax case in the tax case list.

The question is - how can I make sure that the find-Method yields a person entity instance with the taxcase (the first snippet?) Do I have to use explicit commits or some force reloading?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You are finding by a personId. If you want the person to "bring" the associated taxCaseEntity(is), then it depends on how you implemented the entities, the Repository, etc.

Comment: pretty basic entities and JPA repositories in a spring boot app...

Comment: Why not show the actual relationship mappings in the two entities as well? Problem here though is your expectations. You have an EntityManager/persistence context which maintains references to what you give it (via save) and what you are saving is NOT consistent with what gets saved to the database. You are expecting that JPA will rebuild your entity with what is in the DB, but it isn't - if you check, you'd find it is returning the cached instance you gave it, a person with no tax cases. What you pass in is what you get out. the later case uses a separate em, so has no cached instance.

Comment: ok, so does a jpa repository have a way of forcing retrieving an instance that is not cached or updating the cached entity from db?

Comment: I'd recommend you not use it - it is expensive in the long run. JPA is built upon the premise that you should maintain and keep your object model in synch with what you are pushing to the database; which is to say maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships yourself. With your spring example, you are in a transaction, and nothing has yet been committed to the database. You would have to force, prematurely, JPA to flush everything to the database, then issue SQL to reload your person entity. If you must, see https://dzone.com/articles/adding-entitymanagerrefresh-to-all-spring-data-rep